# setattr in monkeypatching of a function throws attribute error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, monkeypatching

I have the following code

`/tests/test_fixme.py`

```
def make_my_patch():
    name = "Dinesh"
    return name


def test_make_patch(monkeypatch):

    monkeypatch.setattr(make_my_patch,"name","DineshKumar")
```

Using `setattr` to set `name` throws an attribute error.

Note : I have placed both the functions in the same file as a stop gap solution to avoid module/import errors for now.

Here is the traceback.

```
================================================================== FAILURES ==================================================================
______________________________________________________________ test_make_patch _______________________________________________________________

monkeypatch = <_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch object at 0x7fddd5675630>

    def test_make_patch(monkeypatch):

>       monkeypatch.setattr(make_my_patch,"name","DineshKumar")
E       AttributeError: <function make_my_patch at 0x7fddd5676048> has no attribute 'name'

tests/test_fixme.py:16: AttributeError
========================================================== short test summary info ===========================================================
FAILED tests/test_fixme.py::test_make_patch - AttributeError: <function make_my_patch at 0x7fddd5676048> has no attribute 'name'
============================================================= 1 failed in 0.02s ==============================================================
(testenv) user@user:~/MyGitHub/MyLearning/Python/MyUnitTests/Testing10$
```

How do I patch the name attribute correctly? However if I place my code inside a class, the setattr for class variable works just fine? Could you please explain why doesnt it work for functions?

Comment: Note that even if you were to monkey patch the ``name`` *attribute*, what the function uses is the ``name`` *local variable*.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi : So how do I actually monkeypatch the `name` variable and force it to use the updated value? And Could you please explain why does this work for classes and why it doesnt in this scenario. I am trying to understand this headon for the past 2 days.

Comment: The function would need to be changed so that it does not use a local variable. I can only assume that your class uses an attribute.

Comment: yeah you are right.I had set `name` as a class variable while using a class.Ideally, since python functions are first class objects, `setattr(make_my_patch,"name","DineshKumar")` works fine.So I assumed that the `setattr` of `monkeypatch` should work too. :(

Answer (score 2):

In case someone ends up here.

You need to return a mock object that has a return value
so your code will be something like:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock

def make_my_patch():
    name = "Dinesh"
    return name


def test_make_patch(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(
        make_my_patch,
        Mock(return_value="DineshKumar")
    )
```